# Does assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2) uses the equals method

Tags: java, junit

In other words, does assertEquals works with a class that overrides `equals`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the [source code of the assertEquals method](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/Assert.java) that you can find on the [Junit GitHub Repo](https://github.com/junit-team/junit):

```
/**
 * Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not
 * an AssertionFailedError is thrown with the given message.
 */
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (expected != null && expected.equals(actual)) {
        return;
    }
    failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}
```

You can see that Junit is using the `.equals()` method.

**Edit:**

The code snippet is coming from a deprecated version of Junit.

You can read about the source of the 'new' Junit [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java). The idea is pretty much the same, the `.equals()` method is also used.

Comment: My issue was that JUnit was saying that equal objects were not equal. Turns out that I didn't override `Object.equals` properly. :)  It helps to add the `@Override` annotation to your method to ensure that you did, in fact, override correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same problem, didn't realize the parameter needed to be of class Object.

Answer (score 10):

> does assertEquals works with a class that overrides equals?

Yes, `assertEquals()` invokes the overridden `equals()` if the class has one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it calls `equals` and there is a separate method, `assertSame`, that uses `==`. Just to clear things up, `assertEquals` works with *any* object since all objects declare `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

```
Object m = new Object() {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("proof!");
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
};
Assert.assertEquals(m, m);
```

Answer (score 1):

JUnit is opensource, so you could have looked it up yourself in the source: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
        Object actual) {
    if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
        return;
    } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else {
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}

private static boolean equalsRegardingNull(Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null) {
        return actual == null;
    }

    return isEquals(expected, actual);
}

private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return expected.equals(actual);
}
```

So as you can see it uses `equals`. If you want to compare identity, you use `assertSame`.

Comment: New URL to the Assert.java source 

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java

Answer (score 1):

yes - TestNG overrides equals -

```
static public void assertEquals(Object actual, Object expected, String message) {
    if((expected == null) && (actual == null)) {
      return;
    }
    if(expected != null) {
      if (expected.getClass().isArray()) {
        assertArrayEquals(actual, expected, message);
        return;
      } else if (expected.equals(actual)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    failNotEquals(actual, expected, message);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is 'yes', however unless the documentation explicitly specifies the behavior of the assertion method you should not assume that `equals` is called in all cases. For example when `expected == actual` or `actual == null` the assertion method might return fast without calling `equals` at all.

JUnit 5's [`Assertions` class](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) mentions this explicitly:

> Assertion methods comparing two objects for *equality*, such as the `assertEquals(expected, actual)` and `assertNotEquals(unexpected, actual)` variants, are *only* intended to test equality for an (un-)expected value and an actual value. They are not designed for testing whether a class correctly implements `Object.equals(Object)`. For example, `assertEquals()` might immediately return `true` when provided the same object for the expected and actual values, without calling `equals(Object)` at all. Tests that aim to verify the `equals(Object)` implementation should instead be written to explicitly verify the `Object.equals(Object)` contract by using `assertTrue()` or `assertFalse()` — for example, `assertTrue(expected.equals(actual))`, `assertTrue(actual.equals(expected))`, `assertFalse(expected.equals(null))`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using chai assert in integration tests, which has a deepEqual that does what the OP wants.

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;
```

...

```
assert.deepEqual(arrayOfObjectsFromApiCall, dummyTestArrayOfObjects)
```

Comment: maybe I missed something, but I wonder how you concluded that the OP wants a `deepEquals`? (after 11 years, and even the answer accepted by OP suggests that `deepEquals` is not what they asked for) Not to speak about the question being marked with the [tag:java] tag - `const` and `require()` indicate that posted code in this answer is NOT Java - I *suspect* it is Javascript, totally unrelated to Java (but for sharing the first 4 letters in the name)