# Junit testing for hashMap with double values

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am using Junit to assert equality berween the expected and actual HashMaps I receive after calling a method. The code looks like this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedKlassToScore, klassToScore);
```

Here `expectedKlassToScore` and `klassToScore` are of type `Map<MyObject, Double>`. Some of the values in the HashMap are upto 16 digits long after the decimals. I am assuming that depending on the machine that these tests run, the last few decimal places might be inaccurate - due to the nature of how fractions are implemented on the hardware.

How can I modify my assert statement to enable a Window of accuracy for letting the tests pass on different machines?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void assertEqualsMapEpsilon(Map<Object,Double> expected, Map<Object,Double> actual, double epsilon) {
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
    for(Map.Entry<Object,Double> value:expected.entrySet()){
        Double actualValue = actual.get(value.getKey());
        assertNotNull(actualValue);
        assertEquals(value.getValue(), actualValue, epsilon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BigDecimal` for this. `Double`s are always inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607597/does-assertequalsobject-o1-object-o2-uses-the-equals-method), Assert.assertEquals uses the equals() method to check if the objects are equal. I'd say the easiest way would be to create a class that implements Map<> and override the equals method.

Comment: Isn't the test then testing the overridden equals method as opposed to the Map itself?

Comment: It is true that in this case you would write specific code to help with the testing and if you get that wrong then the test will behave wrong as well... I suppose if you use this extensively, then you could write a unit test to test the equals method, then use it for subsequent tests.

Answer (score -2):

> Some of the values in the HashMap are upto 16 digits long after the decimals.

Wrong. *None* of the double values in the `HashMap` are up to 16 digits long after the decimals. Double-precision floating-point has a maximum of 15.9 significant decimal digits. Anything else is an illusion.

> I am assuming that depending on the machine that these tests run, the last few decimal places might be inaccurate - due to the nature of how fractions are implemented on the hardware.

Wrong again. The formats and ranges of all primitive types in Java are hardware-independent.

> How can I modify my assert statement to enable a Window of accuracy for letting the tests pass on different machines?

Test for equality within an *epsilon* value.

Comment: -1, but it should be -3.  Your first point - **wrong**.  A double could easily be 16 decimal digits or more, if it is small enough.  It's just that the first few decimal places would be zero.  Your second point - **wrong**.  This depends on how the values in the Map were calculated.  They could be the results of some trigonometrical function, or similar.  Some of the methods in the Math class may have results that are platform dependent - the Javadoc says "Code generators are encouraged to use platform-specific native libraries or microprocessor instructions, where available, to provide ...

Comment: ... higher-performance implementations of Math methods".  Your third point - aren't you just restating the question?  "How do I have a window of accuracy?" - "Test with an epsilon value" - "What's an epsilon value?" - "Well it's a window of accuracy".   And what do 15.9 decimal digits look like anyway?  You either mean it's a maximum of 15, or you mean it's a maximum of 16, or you mean something else entirely.

Comment: @DavidWallace Re point 1, leading zeros have nothing to do with *significant* digits. Point 2 relates to the OP's claim about 'how fractions are calculated on the hardware', which is machine-independent in Java. Re point 3, I agree that *epsilon* ***is*** the window: that's the point. *Epsilon* is well-defined: 'window' isn't.