# JUnit's assertEquals denies assertTrue

Tags: java, junit, double, point

Let's say I've got my own class `Point` with `double X, double Y`;

```
public class Point {

    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Point point){
        return x == point.x && y == point.y;
    }
}
```

I have also written a test for it

```
    assertEquals(new Point(0.0, 5.0), new Point(0.0, 5.0));
```

and guess what? **It fails**. I was sure it was about a double comparison unless I tried this:

```
assertTrue(new Point(0.0, 5.0).equals(new Point(0.0, 5.0)));
```

and it **SUCCED**!

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607662/2047418 `assertEquals`  calls `equals` method for the class (to ensure I checked it on my own by debugger and indeed it does) so how is it possible that `assertEquals` fails but `assetTrue` passes?!

Comment: Both answers are correct. A little additional help for you: If you intend to override a method, annotate it with `@Override` (modern IDEs do that automatically for you, look for it). The compiler is then able to detect whether the method actually does override a method. In your case, the compiler would have detected an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not overriding the `Object#equals()` method properly -- its signature should be as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
```

The parameter must be of type `Object`, you would then convert it to `Point`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Point other = (Point) obj;
    return x == other.x && y == other.y;
}
```

Comment: @Filip This is why you should use `@Override` whenever you believe you are overriding a method. The compiler would have complained at your original code.

Comment: Does it mean that `assertEquals(new Point(0.0, 5.0), new Point(0.0, 5.0));` don't call `Point.equals` but... `Object.equals()`?

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Yes It calls the (_overriden_) `Object.equals()`, the one that takes `Object` as argument. The `Point.equals()` originally in the question is completely different and is therefore not called by the assert.

Comment: What about using 'super' in place of 3 'if statements'

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: `assertEquals` does not call the `equals` method that you wrote yourself, because it doesn't override `Object.equals(Object)`.

Your `equals` method accepts a `Point` parameter, which is a totally different method. Your second test using `assertTrue` simply calls that method directly.