# assertEquals fail tests despite same lists

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, assertion

I want to test equality of two lists - actual (which is returned by tested method) and expected (which is hardcoded by me).
I'm looking at these two lists for a hour and I cannot see any difference between them.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<[Book{title='Pokrzyk', author='Puzyńska Katarzyna'}, Book{title='Odbiorę ci wszystko', author='Lillegraven Ruth'}, Book{title='Nóż. Harry Hole. Tom 12', author='Nesbo Jo'}, Book{title='Za zamkniętymi drzwiami', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Coraz większy mrok', author='Hoover Colleen'}, Book{title='Ta, która musi umrzeć', author='Lagercrantz David'}, Book{title='Teraz zaśniesz', author='Taylor C. L.'}, Book{title='Na skraju załamania', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Listy zza grobu', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Rewizja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 3', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Odwet', author='Severski Vincent V.'}, Book{title='Immunitet. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 4', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Inwigilacja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 5', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Zniknięcie Annie Thorne', author='Tudor C. J.'}, Book{title='Kontratyp. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 8', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[Book{title='Pokrzyk', author='Puzyńska Katarzyna'}, Book{title='Odbiorę ci wszystko', author='Lillegraven Ruth'}, Book{title='Nóż. Harry Hole. Tom 12', author='Nesbo Jo'}, Book{title='Za zamkniętymi drzwiami', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Coraz większy mrok', author='Hoover Colleen'}, Book{title='Ta, która musi umrzeć', author='Lagercrantz David'}, Book{title='Teraz zaśniesz', author='Taylor C. L.'}, Book{title='Na skraju załamania', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Listy zza grobu', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Rewizja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 3', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Odwet', author='Severski Vincent V.'}, Book{title='Immunitet. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 4', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Inwigilacja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 5', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Zniknięcie Annie Thorne', author='Tudor C. J.'}, Book{title='Kontratyp. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 8', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}]>
Expected :java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<[Book{title='Pokrzyk', author='Puzyńska Katarzyna'}, Book{title='Odbiorę ci wszystko', author='Lillegraven Ruth'}, Book{title='Nóż. Harry Hole. Tom 12', author='Nesbo Jo'}, Book{title='Za zamkniętymi drzwiami', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Coraz większy mrok', author='Hoover Colleen'}, Book{title='Ta, która musi umrzeć', author='Lagercrantz David'}, Book{title='Teraz zaśniesz', author='Taylor C. L.'}, Book{title='Na skraju załamania', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Listy zza grobu', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Rewizja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 3', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Odwet', author='Severski Vincent V.'}, Book{title='Immunitet. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 4', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Inwigilacja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 5', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Zniknięcie Annie Thorne', author='Tudor C. J.'}, Book{title='Kontratyp. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 8', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}]> 
Actual   :java.util.ArrayList<[Book{title='Pokrzyk', author='Puzyńska Katarzyna'}, Book{title='Odbiorę ci wszystko', author='Lillegraven Ruth'}, Book{title='Nóż. Harry Hole. Tom 12', author='Nesbo Jo'}, Book{title='Za zamkniętymi drzwiami', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Coraz większy mrok', author='Hoover Colleen'}, Book{title='Ta, która musi umrzeć', author='Lagercrantz David'}, Book{title='Teraz zaśniesz', author='Taylor C. L.'}, Book{title='Na skraju załamania', author='Paris B.A.'}, Book{title='Listy zza grobu', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Rewizja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 3', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Odwet', author='Severski Vincent V.'}, Book{title='Immunitet. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 4', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Inwigilacja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 5', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}, Book{title='Zniknięcie Annie Thorne', author='Tudor C. J.'}, Book{title='Kontratyp. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 8', author='Mróz Remigiusz'}]>
```

The only difference I see is that at the end of Expected line is blank space dont know why, but I think it should not failing my tests as it tests whether elements are the same.

Test:

```
package bookstore.scraper.fetcher.empik;

import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EmpikFetchingBookServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    EmpikFetchingBookService empikFetchingBookService;

    @Test
    public void get15BooksFromCrimeCategory() throws IOException {
        File in = getFile("/CrimeCategoryEmpik.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");

        List<Book> actualBooks = empikFetchingBookService.get15BooksFromCategory(doc);
        List<Book> expectedBooks = prepare15CrimeBooks();

        assertEquals(expectedBooks, actualBooks);
    }

    private static File getFile(String resourceName) {
        try {
            return new File(EmpikFetchingBookServiceTest.class.getResource(resourceName).toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private List<Book> prepare15CrimeBooks() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Puzyńska Katarzyna").withTitle("Pokrzyk").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Lillegraven Ruth").withTitle("Odbiorę ci wszystko").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Nesbo Jo").withTitle("Nóż. Harry Hole. Tom 12").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Paris B.A.").withTitle("Za zamkniętymi drzwiami").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Hoover Colleen").withTitle("Coraz większy mrok").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Lagercrantz David").withTitle("Ta, która musi umrzeć").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Taylor C. L.").withTitle("Teraz zaśniesz").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Paris B.A.").withTitle("Na skraju załamania").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Mróz Remigiusz").withTitle("Listy zza grobu").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Mróz Remigiusz").withTitle("Rewizja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 3").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Severski Vincent V.").withTitle("Odwet").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Mróz Remigiusz").withTitle("Immunitet. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 4").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Mróz Remigiusz").withTitle("Inwigilacja. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 5").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Tudor C. J.").withTitle("Zniknięcie Annie Thorne").build(),
                new Book.BookBuilder().withAuthor("Mróz Remigiusz").withTitle("Kontratyp. Joanna Chyłka. Tom 8").build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share equals method for Book?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607597/does-assertequalsobject-o1-object-o2-uses-the-equals-method), the assertEquals method uses the equals method, which compares whether the actual object instances are the same. To solve your issue, you should override the equal() method to determine whether the values themselves are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @omoshiroiii answered, consider using AssertJ as a dependency for assertions. There is a whole documentation [here](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html) about asserting lists, and you can also assert object field values using things like:

```
assertThat(expectedObject).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(actualObject);
```

Comment: Why is it better than "traditional" `assertEquals`?

Comment: If you have two objects, both of them with field1 and field2, and you want to compare both objects with respect to the their field values: You can use the `isEqualToComparingFieldByField` method I showed instead of comparing field1 to field1, and field2 to field2 individually, for example. The dependency has many helpers like those, and is a standard for assertions... It is even included on Spring boot starter test dependency.